# React native - Where is the problem. function repeats constantly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

React native - Where is the problem. _getUser repeats constantly. Help me please.

```
const _getUser = async () => {
    setLoading(false);
    var userid = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userid');
    let options = "";
    return fetch('x', options)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        setLoading(true);
      })
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    _getUser();
    return () => {
       _getUser
    };
  }, [navigation, loading]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting loading in the _getUser function, and you effect is listening to changes for to loading, causing the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `loading` from the `useEffect` dependency array, cause you're setting it again after you get the user results

`[navigation]`

Comment: I'm not sure why actually are you calling `_getUser` while unmounting. Is that really necessary?

Comment: when closing the page all states must be removed

Comment: unmounting a component means you're removing the component from DOM which eventually by itself will remove the state of the component. No need to do it explicitly.